# Wordpress WPML not translating get_option

Tags: wordpress, wpml

i am trying to translate my plugin options through WPML but it is not working.
Here is how i have placed my string in the plugin file

```
get_option(_e('my_label','my-text-domain'));
```

I have already scan my plugin through the WPML and have done translation in "German" while default is English.

Can anyone help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `_e` *outputs* the translated text.

You want `__` (double underscore), which will *return* the translated text.

I would explore other solutions to this problem. In general you shouldn't be using translation to determine what option to pull from the database. The functionality of your plugin should not hinge on whether or not the translated text is a valid option name.

An alternative approach may be to use [`get_locale`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_locale) to fetch the current locale and then use that to determine the option name:

```
$option_name = get_locale() . 'my_label';
$label = get_option( $option_name );
```

Now you can still get the localized version of your option, without depending on translators to input the correct option name.

If you have to use the translation approach, I would use [`_x`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_x) to explain that the translated text should be an option key.

```
get_option( _x('my_label', 'Must be a valid option name', 'my-text-domain') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have multiple entries in your meta table per language, try the double underscore function?:

```
get_option( __( 'my_label','my-text-domain' ) );
```